# Is it possible to use the MongooseJS' query#populate method recursively?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose we have a schema A which looks like:

`{ b: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'B' }`,

a type B which looks like:

`{ c: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'C' }`,

and a type C which looks like:

`{ name: String }`.

Is there any way to use MongooseJS' populate utility to get at documents through multiple refs? In the example, we could find A's b by doing

```
A.findOne({ id: someId })
    .populate('b')
    ...
```

but could we get at b's c through A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not currently. Some support for this is coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think things changed since two years. What about the following Model.populate() use:

```
A.findOne({id: someId})
 .populate('b')
 .exec()
 .then(function(data) {
         // returns a promise about populating a.b.c:
         return C.populate(data, {path: 'b.c'});
     });
```

Details can be found in the 3.6' Release Notes: 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#added-modelpopulatedocs-opts-cb